# Butterknife Suddenly Stopped Working

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, butterknife

Yesterday I was working on my on going project using butterknife in it.But suddenly its stopped working.The `ButterKnife.bind(this)` is not able to bind the views so that all the views are throwing `NullPointerException`.I don't understand what happened that suddenly its stop working.Its a weird situation

Here are few points which i already did but its not working

1. Using Latest version currently i am using 8.8.1
2. Using old version i tried with 8.0.1 and 8.6.0
3. Clean and Rebuild
4. Invalidate Cache
5. Removing Gradle and Build files

Following are the version i am using

```
ext {
    // sdk and tools
    minSdkVersion = 21
    targetSdkVersion = 27
    compileSdkVersion = 27
    buildToolsVersion = '26.0.2'

    // dependencies versions
    supportLibraryVersion = '27.0.0'
    playServicesVersion = '10.2.4'
    butterKnifeVersion = '8.8.1'
    retrofitVersion = '2.3.0'

}
```

I am banging my head from past 8 Hours on this silly issue.If anyone could help will be appropriated

Comment: Did you updated to Android3.0? There's a guide to migrate to the new gradle version

Comment: Yes i did...Current i am working on 3.0.1...but in 3.0.1 it was working fine yesterday

Comment: Also, check https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/1127 and see if the  9.0.0-SNAPSHOT works for you

Comment: How about using `buildToolsVersion '27.0.0'`?

Comment: Upgrading `buildToolsVersion` did not work @ישואוהבאותך

Comment: `it was working fine yesterday` did your OS is Windows and is crashed yesterday?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally i found the solution.Ii was due to Kotlin Plugin. It was happening since I updated the Kotlin plugin in Android Studio 3.0

If you are using Kotlin then `annotationProcessor` wont work instead you need to use `kapt`

So replace this

```
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
```

with this

```
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
kapt'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
```

It will resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

There can be 2 possibilities:

1. Your external dependency is not upgraded, check "External Libraries" section of your project and compare if it is upgraded to latest version or not i.e. 8.8.1  (also try to make gradle offline work)
2. If you are upgraded to Android plugin for Gradle 3.0 or higher than your project automatically uses default version of buildTools https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/build-tools.html#notes

Comment: I have checked the external libraries its 8.8.1 only